# Quid significat "-amen"?

Tags: affixes

Quid suffixum **-amen** significat, ut **foramen**, **putamen**, **calceamen**, **regimen**, **æquamen**, **vocamen**, etc.?

**-amen** suffixo in dictionariis interretialibus non invenio, neque perspicuam significationem communem in verbis eo factis. **Foramen** est *id quod est factum* **forando**, tamen **æquamen** est *instrumentum* ad **æquandum** (ut dicit Forcellini [hic](http://linguax.com/lexica/forc.php?searchedLG=foramen) et [hic](http://linguax.com/lexica/forc.php?searchedLG=aequamen)). Intellego **-amen** nomen a verbo temporis facere, sed quomodo ab **-atio**, **-mentum**, etc. differt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suffixum *-men* instrumentum significat.
Si verbum coniugationis primae est, adest *-a-*, sed pars est verbi, non suffixi.

*Calceamen* est aliquid, quo calceare possumus.
*Nomen* est aliqued, quo noscere possumus.
Similiter *velamine* velamus et *regimine* regimus.

Suffixum *-mentum* idem significat ac *-men* — sic saltem narrat ars grammatica mea.
*Ornamento* ornamus, *documento* docemus et sic porro.

Suffixum *-tio/-sio* (aut *-io*, sed semper cum stemmate participii perfecti adhibetur) dissimile est.
Hoc, ut ita dicam, phaenomenon significat: *scriptio* est phaenomenon in quo aliquid scribitur, in *possessione* aliquid possidetur, in *dictatione* aliquid dictatur et sic porro.

Suffixum *-men/-mentum* instrumentum tangibile dat, *-io* phaenomenon abstractum.
Certe *velamen(tum)* in *velatione* usui est!

De vocabulis *foramen*, *putamen* et *regimen* (de commentariis):
Usus abstractus vocabuli *regimen* sensum extensum habet, sed nihilo minus instrumentum alicuius generis significat.
*Foramen* venit e vocabulo *foras* (foramine foras ire possumus), non ex ullo verbo.
Crediderim vocabulum *putamen* sensum multo extensum habere, sed nescio qualis sit historia etymologica eius.

**English summary:**
The suffix *-men* means an instrument, just like *-mentum*.
The suffix *-tio/-sio*, on the other hand, means a phenomenon.
The instrument is a concrete thing but the phenomenon is more abstract.
Sometimes the meaning of derived words has been extended quite a bit, but often one can still see these underlying rules.

Comment: Studium excitat. Sed nonne **regimen** abstractum est, ut _Regimen Sanitatis Salernitanum_ —aut hoc est sensus extensus? Et suntne **putamen**, **foramen**, **purgamentum** exceptiones?

Comment: @BenKovitz, usus abstractus vocabuli *regimen* sensum extensum habet. *Foramen* venit de vocabulo *foras* (per foramine foras ire possumus), non de ullo verbo. Crediderim vocabulum *putamen* sensum multo extensum habere, sed nescio qualis sit historia etymologica eius.